# typescript construct to handle optional object type

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function, `findUser` that I would like to have as inputs either a username (as a string) or a `user_id` as a number.

```
function findUser(info: { user_id: number } | { username: string}) {
  if (info.user_id) {

  }
  if (info.username) {

  }
}
```

I'm getting the typescript error on the `info.user_id` clearly because the `user_id` field it is not guaranteed to exist on `info`.

I realize an alternative way to do this is to define the function as

```
function findUser(info: { user_id?: number; username?: string}) {
```

and then it works, however clearly you can pass in an empty object and it would be nice to have a way to check against this.

(Also, I have a more-complicated structure with 4 types of inputs. And I think if I solve this simpler example, I can determine the more complicated one.)

My question: is there a way in typescript to do something like the first function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define both alternatives as type:

```
  type UserInfo = { user_id: number; username?: string; } | { user_id?: number; username: string };

  function findUser(info: UserInfo ) {
```

Note that this way will allow providing both `user_id` and `username`. If this is not desired, you can use `never` type:

```
  type UserInfo = { user_id: number; username?: never; } | { user_id?: never; username: string };

  function findUser(info: UserInfo ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use interfaces or a fast way like this

```
const findUser: { (name: string) : void; (Id: number): void; } = (value: string | number): void => {
if (typeof value === typeof 'string') { console.log("find by name") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way

```js
interface PropsName {
  userName: string
  userId?: string
}

interface PropsID {
  userId: string
  userName?: string
}

function findUser(info: PropsName | PropsID) {
  if (info.userId) {
    
  }
  if (info.userName) {

  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACACrA9gBwM4ByiAtugN7BpoCu%20cxZAXGvpLBAOZW32wCSAEwD8LNh3DcAviAgwEKdFjz5%20AETSVqdOELHsuPHbEbRRrA5JAyQ8GuGSRQ2cGngRBAVT4AKCPGwWZQJTNAAfTBwCdQBKTR5QeDQ-cACAOmMhOK00GWpE5P9sDL5TbJBqGSkgA)